# Excel: Combining SUMPRODUCT with SUBTOTAL when counting range of cells higher than another range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi Super User community,

I'm currently using a SUMPRODUCT formula `SUMPRODUCT(--(H101:H106<L101:L106))`

This formula returns a number that shows how many cells in the H101:H106 range is higher than the equivalent cell across in L101:L106.

What i'm trying to do is combine this with SUBTOTAL, so that that formula only compares with the rows I filter with. I've done some searching and I've seen some complicated solutions that combine the SUBTOTAL formula with OFFSET but I can't quite figure out how to make this work with what i'm trying to achieve.

Hope this makes sense and thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic is that you need to create an array that is the same number of rows as the other boolean then multiply them together.

To create the array True/False on whether it is visible or not is:

```
SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(H101,ROW(H101:H106)-MIN(ROW(H101:H106)),0))>0
```

`ROW(H101:H106)-MIN(ROW(H101:H106))` returns an array of, in this case of `{0;1;2;3;4;5}`

Then that array is passed to the OFFSET and an array of the ranges are passed to the SUBTOTAL.

We use `3` or `COUNTA` to know if the row is visible or not.  This will return a vertical array of TRUE/FALSE, `TRUE` will be returned if the row is visible and `FALSE` if not.

So combining your formula and SUBTOTAL:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(H101,ROW(H101:H106)-MIN(ROW(H101:H106)),0))>0)*(H101:H106<L101:L106))
```

Will get the count where both the row is visible and the value in H is less than the value in L.

One Note:  I do forget if this requires Ctrl-Shift-Enter in older versions or not.

Comment: Thank you so much - this works perfectly. Really appreciate your help.